Ubuntu 24.04 LTS You Tube and other websites don't connect on ANY browser?
I used both firefox and chrome (I had problems with chrome installation and it only worked with the ppa, if that helps).
On Firefox it shows "Unable to connect"
On Chrome it shows "This site can't be reached".
GitHub on the other hand, doesn't load the UI at all and I can only see the basic html, aka only the text and the blue links.
I am certain the internet connection is not to be blamed at all. The only other solution I found online was to turn off hardware acceleration, and that didn't help.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!
EDIT: Solution was to follow this: Ubuntu 22.04 is connected to internet, but cannot open any website in the browser

You can write your own answer, and after a bit, accept it, helping others and gaining some reputation points in the process.

If you do make your own answer please do not just have a link. A link only is considered a non answer. The contents of the steps in that link need to also be in the answer.

Does this answer your question? Ubuntu 22.04 is connected to internet, but cannot open any website in the browser

The solution was to follow this:
Ubuntu 22.04 is connected to internet, but cannot open any website in the browser
Seems like my ISP had some sort of issue assigning a DNS to my system, a problem unique to my Linux OS and not Windows.
Solved it by going to Settings
--> Wi-Fi
--> Clicked on the settings of the network I was using
--> IPv4 Tab at the top
--> Toggle Off Automatic for DNS field
--> enter 8.8.8.8 in DNS field.
